# how can I use multithreading in electron-vite-vuejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, vite

I'm trying to use the separate thread in my electronjs app, for creating the app I used this way https://github.com/electron-vite/electron-vite-vue and in my main process in index.ts file I create worker (I wrote the code in eval because it was unable to find the worker file after build, also it works okay in development mode, but when I am building it for production, it not works), if there is more correct way to create a worker or to make this one work, please help me

```js
import cron from "node-cron";
import {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
} from "electron";
import path, { join } from "node:path";
import Store from "electron-store";
import diskinfo from "node-disk-info";
const store = new Store();
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
// const workerPath = path.join(__dirname, 'workers/diskSpaceControl.js');

// The built directory structure
//
// ├─┬ dist-electron
// │ ├─┬ main
// │ │ └── index.js    > Electron-Main
// │ └─┬ preload
// │   └── index.js    > Preload-Scripts
// ├─┬ dist
// │ └── index.html    > Electron-Renderer
//
process.env.DIST_ELECTRON = join(__dirname, "..");
process.env.DIST = join(process.env.DIST_ELECTRON, "../dist");
process.env.PUBLIC = process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL
  ? join(process.env.DIST_ELECTRON, "../public")
  : process.env.DIST;

// Disable GPU Acceleration for Windows 7
if (release().startsWith("6.1")) app.disableHardwareAcceleration();

// Set application name for Windows 10+ notifications
if (process.platform === "win32") app.setAppUserModelId(app.getName());

if (!app.requestSingleInstanceLock()) {
  app.quit();
  process.exit(0);
}


let win: BrowserWindow | null = null;
// Here, you can also use other preload
const preload = join(__dirname, "../preload/index.js");
const url = process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL;
const indexHtml = join(process.env.DIST, "index.html");
let tray = null;
async function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    title: `Saber Delivery Client ${app.getVersion()} ${
      process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL ? "(dev)" : ""
    }`,
    icon: join(process.env.PUBLIC, "logo-default.png"),
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload,
      // Warning: Enable nodeIntegration and disable contextIsolation is not secure in production
      // Consider using contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld
      // Read more on https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true
    },
  });
  if (process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // electron-vite-vue#298
    win.loadURL(url);
    // win.webContents.openDevTools();
    // Open devTool if the app is not packaged

    win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: "bottom" });
  } else {
    win.setMenu(null);
    win.loadFile(indexHtml);
  }

  // Test actively push message to the Electron-Renderer
  win.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
    win?.webContents.send("main-process-message", new Date().toLocaleString());
  });

  // Make all links open with the browser, not with the application
  win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
    if (url.startsWith("https:")) shell.openExternal(url);
    return { action: "deny" };
  });

  win.on("close", (e) => {
    if (win.isVisible()) {
      e.preventDefault();
      win.hide();
    }
  });
  // win.webContents.on('will-navigate', (event, url) => { }) #344
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

const worker = new Worker(`
const Store = require("electron-store");
const diskinfo = require("node-disk-info");
const cron = require("node-cron");
const path = require("path");

const store = new Store();

cron.schedule("* * * * * *", async () => {
  
    try {
      const roamingFolderPath = process.env.APPDATA
      store.path = path.join(roamingFolderPath,'saber-delivery','config.json') 
      const downloads = await store.get("downloads");
      const freeDiskSpace = await store.get("freeDiskSpace");
      const result = [] 
      freeDiskSpace.forEach((disk) => {
        const filteredDownloads = downloads.filter((item) =>
          typeof item.build_size === 'number' && item.downloadedPath.includes(disk.diskPath)
        );
      
        const total = filteredDownloads.reduce(
          (acc, item) => acc + (item.build_size - (item.total_done || 0)),
          0
        );
      
        result.push({ path: disk.diskPath, total: total });
      });
  
      
      const diskSpaceInfo = diskinfo.getDiskInfoSync();
      const freeDiskSpaces = diskSpaceInfo
        .filter((item) => item.filesystem === "Local Fixed Disk")
        .map((item) => ({ free: item.mounted.includes('C')?item.available - 21474836480:item.available, diskPath: item.mounted }));
      const res = result.map((item) => {
        const found = freeDiskSpaces.find((freeDiskSpace) =>
          freeDiskSpace.diskPath.includes(item.path)
        );
      
        if (found) {
          return { free: found.free - item.total, diskPath: item.path };
        }
      
        return { free: 0, diskPath: item.path }; 
      });

      store.set("freeDiskSpace", res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
`,{eval:true});
```